# MongoDB: latest value for every field

Tags: mongodb, group-by, database

I have a collection like this:

```js
{
    _id : 1,
    key : "one",
    date : ISODate("2016-10-18 08:00.000"),
    a : "a1",
    b : "b1"
},
{
    _id : 2,
    key : "two",
    date : ISODate("2016-10-18 09:00.000"),
    a : "a2",
    b : "b2"
},
{
    _id : 3,
    key : "one",
    date : ISODate("2016-10-18 10:00.000"),
    b : "b3",
    c : "c3"
},
{
    _id : 4,
    key : "one",
    date : ISODate("2016-10-18 11:00.000"),
    b : "b4"
}
```

I would like to run a single procedure that returns for every field its lastest value (based on the field `date`), so for the previous collection I would receive this result:

```js
{
    _id : "one",
    a : "a1",
    b : "b4",
    c : "c3"
},
{
    _id : "two",
    a : "a2",
    b : "b2"
}
```

I have tried with many `aggregate` using `match`, `sort`, `group` but without success ...

Comment: Expected result is correct?

Comment: @NEER, sorry, the expected result was wrong, I correct it now. Thank you.

Comment: are you grouping by the `key` value? the projected fields are dynamic? or will be always the same?

Comment: are you using `mongoose` or something similar so you can know the possible fields of the schema using `javascript` ?

Comment: @TomG, yes, I'm grouping by the `key` value; yes, the projected fields are dynamic. And I read the collection using the Java driver so, yes, I could know all the possible fields, but in all my tests this operation limits the speed of the entire excecution.

Comment: basically `aggregation` functions are not that fast, but it should be good enough. please see my full answer.

Comment: @Tom why do you think that aggregation is not fast? Do you have any benchmark test result to show? I will be very happy to know.

Comment: @Styvane I just said it because Michele wrote something about speed limits, nothing specific against `aggregation` which I use a lot. What I meant was that it's slower than one `find` query since `aggregate` uses index only in the first stage, so the rest of the stages are slower

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is `sort` the documents by the `date` and then `group` and `$push` the values so the latest value will be the first element in the new arrays after the `group` stage. after that, in the `$project` stage, use [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) in order to show the latest value. in case the array is empty (like in your example with `key: two`), the value will not be projected as your expected result. For your example it will look something like this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    {
        $sort: {
            date: -1
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$key',
            a: {$push: '$a'},
            b: {$push: '$b'},
            c: {$push: '$c'}
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            a: {$arrayElemAt: ['$a', 0]},
            b: {$arrayElemAt: ['$b', 0]},
            c: {$arrayElemAt: ['$c', 0]}
        }
    }
])
```

The only problem with this solution is that you have the know the fields names. it's not possible to do a "generic" aggregation that will do that on all the available fields. So if you know the possible fields, it's not a problem. If you are using it using `mongoose` or something similar, you can use the `schema` to build a dynamic `$group` and `$project` stages using `javascript` before calling the `aggregate` function.

Comment: @TomG, I waited a little hoping someone else answers ... but you win :)